# Do we have a formula to determine number of cycles in a complete graph?

Tags: graph-theory

I just read the formula to determining the no. of paths of length $m$. It was $\frac{n(n-1)\cdots(n-m)}{2}$

Do we have something for cycles too?I think it should be $\frac{n(n-1)\cdots (n-m+1)}{2}$. Does this make any sense?

It is just a basic question so if you think it is not something to response then I humbly request you to not answer but please don't downvote this. As I this is my first course in graph theory! (In complete graphs) *
Thanks

Comment: You mean in the complete graph?

Comment: Yes, sorry ....

Comment: So, how did you come up with your idea?

Comment: It's just simply concluded by me by choosing the vertices but the last vertix must be same as first so I didn't choose last one

Comment: As we needed m+1 vertices for m length so m vertices can be chosen in unwritten ways!

Comment: The link is somehow helpful but I wanna talk about this like, I don't know, I am just curious about this and wanna understand this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each $m\ge 3$ and each path $P$ of length $m-1$ we can obtain a cycle $f(P)$ of length $m$ by joining the last vertex of $P$ to its first vertex. Conversely, from each cycle $C$  of length $m$ we can obtain a path $g(C)$ of length $m-1$ by removing the last edge of $C$. It is easy to see that the function $f$ is a bijection and $f^{-1}=g$. So the number of cycles of length $m$ equals to the number of paths of length $m-1$, which is $n(n-1)\dots (n-m+1)$. I think this value differs from yours due to the defintions of a path. I think in your definition a path is a graph, whereas I consider it as a sequence of vertices. See also [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3741515/graph-theory-questions-about-hamiltonian-cycles/3741721#3741721) recent answer discussing a definition of a Hamiltonian cycle.